# close popup react-leaflet after user click on button in popup

Tags: reactjs, popup, leaflet, react-leaflet

So basically want to make custom close for react-leaflet Popup component, seams that is not a big problem to do with native API leaflet but with react component from react-leaflet I can't find the solution.

Comment: I also want to have onClick property in <Tooltip /> component, but seems not present currently. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

at the moment, the only way I found to close the popup is the following:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.popup = React.createRef();
}

// the magic
closePopusOnClick(){
    this.popup.current.leafletElement.options.leaflet.map.closePopup();
}

render(){
    return <Marker position={[this.props.lat, this.props.lng]}>
        <Popup ref={this.popup}>
            <Button onClick={this.closePopusOnClick}>Close popup</Button>
        </Popup>
    </Marker>;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 3):

In `"react-leaflet": "^3.0.2"` I managed to close the popup with:

```
popupRef.current._closeButton.click()
```

Not very nice comparing to a future `Popup.close()` method which MUST work out-of-box, but gets the job done...

Comment: Do you have any way to do it with RL4 and Typescript?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with a similar solution to [Luca's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54874575/4079967), so I thought I'd add it as an answer too. I needed to close all popups when moving or zooming the map and ended up with the following:

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import { Map } from "react-leaflet"

export default () => {
  const mapRef = useRef(null);

  const closePopups = () => {
    mapRef.current.leafletElement.closePopup();
  };

  const handleOnDragend = e => {
    closePopups();
  };

  const handleOnZoomend = e => {
    closePopups();
  };

  if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
    return null;
  }

  return (
      <Map
        ref={mapRef}
        onDragend={handleOnDragend}
        onZoomend={handleOnZoomend}
      >
      </Map>
  )
}
```

This can, however, be extended so that anything can call the `closePopups` method.

Answer (score 0):

I found the working solution for `react-leaflet` v3 by modifying these two links codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/4ws0i and https://stackoverflow.com/a/67750291/8339172

here is the function to hide the `Popup` component

```js
const hideElement = () => {
  if (!popupElRef.current || !map) return;
  map.closePopup();
};
```

here is the `Popup` component

```js
<Popup ref={popupElRef} closeButton={false}>
  <button onClick={hideElement}>Close popup</button>
</Popup>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the latest `react-leaflet` `Map` simply has a `closePopup()` method. Here is a working example with `MapContainer`.

```
const [map, setMap] = useState<Map|null>(null);
return (
  <MapContainer ref={setMap} center={[44,44]} zoom={7}>
    <TileLayer
      attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
      url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
    />
    <Marker position={[44,44]}>
      <Popup>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            map && map.closePopup();
          }}
        >
          Close me!
        </button>
      </Popup>
    </Marker>
  </MapContainer>
);
```